# How to detect tweets posted from official account?

Tags: twitter, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am doing a research project which wants to work out Hong Kong people's attitudes toward the public transportation system. I have collected millions of tweets using [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/content/developer-twitter/en.html). Since my research target is local Hong Kong people, tweets posted from official accounts or tweets contain advertisements may be useless.

Hence, could anyone give some hint about how to filter out the tweets posted from the official account? I know my explanation might be a little bit abstract. Any tips would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If you mean "verified" accounts with the blue check logo, in the tweet JSON, you have `json.user.verified` set to true for verified users.

Comment: @JeffProd Oh, thank you for your prompt reply! I will check this in my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can request the user object [get information about a user](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show) and test if the `verified` key is set to true. here is the informations you get [returned informations in JSON](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object),  you can see that the key `verified` is among the result.